# iOS DeviceCheck query two bits not working

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, devicecheck

I have updated two bits last week on my iPad 7th generation. iPadOS 13.5.1 using iPad app I'm developing.

When I query device check (query two bits) next day I did get two bytes as I updated. I tried again after 1 week query two bits, unfortunately I didn't get reply expected. Here is a json I received.

```
{"status":200,"data":"Failed to find bit state"}
```

Failed to find bit state, I should have get when bit state is never updated as far as I understand. But, I updated device two bits state a week ago. I should have received two bits state with last updated yyyy-mm.

Can you please look in to it and help me? Am I missing anything?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you didn’t mix up the development server and production server?

Comment: I haven't. I am using apple's development server for testing. I can post server javascript code if you say. I'm struggling to resolve it and have no alternative for DeviceCheck

Comment: Adding the code always helps finding issues, if not by me, then by others. Also, here's an example project by marinosoftware (unrelated) that might be a bit older but still holds up and works. You can compare what you have with the stuff there to see if you can find any discrepancies: https://github.com/marinosoftware/DeviceCheckSample

Just make sure you've registered the BundleID in your developer portal if you want to successfully use the development server with this sample. If it's not registered you'll get a 400 code back with something about tokens not being correctly formatted.

Comment: I switched to production server https://api.devicecheck.apple.com, just to see the difference from https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com for development and how it handles query_two_bits. I noticed production server works just fine even in development mode of an app. Responded two bits, mm-yyyy as it was set a week ago. I think development server just saves data for a day or so. If you query_two_bits to development server after week, it will only reply status 200 with no bits information or timestamp. I think development does not keep data more than 48 hours.